# Spring Cloud Data Flow aggregator example

Tags: spring, spring-xd, spring-cloud-dataflow

Can anybody point to some examples specific to String Cloud Data Flow (not Stream XD) on how to write splitters and aggregators?

In particular non trivial splitting and joining of messages. Any non trivial example of complex streams. How do you define a stream that is aggregating messages after spliting, how about when there are Routers and diferent processing for the produced messages, how is all that aggregated later?

PS: Sorry for the long question, I will clarify as needed.
thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an out of the box app available for `splitter` [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/splitter). The aggregator is yet to be added to the OOTB apps and is being tracked [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/app-starters-release/issues/15). You can write an app based on [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html#aggregator) and your contributions are welcome!

Comment: Thanks! I have read the links provided, and some more that might be useful in case somebody finds this question: [link]https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters it contains other starters. The generator I ended up with based on the documentation is very simple, a method with the @Agregator annotation, a list of Message as parameter and returning a single Message result... Still does not answer the problem of examples of complex streams.

Comment: I will mark this as answer as it gives good references, but would be nice to have more complex examples published...